# Failed to build npm modules on CentOS 7

Tags: node.js, centos7

I am trying to build keeweb on CentOS 7, but it seems some NodeJS errors during the compilation:

```
[root@localhost keeweb]# npm install
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v10.2.1
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8, 9.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/

> iltorb@https://registry.npmjs.org/iltorb/-/iltorb-1.0.13.tgz install /home/bilyes/Desktop/keeweb/node_modules/iltorb
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/home/bilyes/Desktop/keeweb/node_modules/iltorb/build'
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/decode/brotli/common/dictionary.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/decode/brotli/dec/bit_reader.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/decode/brotli/dec/decode.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/decode/brotli/dec/huffman.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/decode/brotli/dec/state.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/decode/src/common/allocator.o
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:190:0,
                 from ../src/common/allocator.cc:2:
../../nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h: In function ‘Nan::Maybe<bool> Nan::ForceSet(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::PropertyAttribute)’:
../../nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:112:15: error: ‘class v8::Object’ has no member named ‘ForceSet’
   return obj->ForceSet(isolate->GetCurrentContext(), key, value, attribs);
               ^
In file included from ../src/common/allocator.cc:2:0:
../../nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::MakeCallback(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Function>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’:
../../nan/nan.h:833:60: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> node::MakeCallback(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Function>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’ is deprecated (declared at /root/.node-gyp/10.2.1/include/node/node.h:171): Use MakeCallback(..., async_context) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), target, func, argc, argv);
                                                            ^
../../nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::MakeCallback(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::String>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’:
../../nan/nan.h:848:62: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> node::MakeCallback(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::String>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’ is deprecated (declared at /root/.node-gyp/10.2.1/include/node/node.h:164): Use MakeCallback(..., async_context) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), target, symbol, argc, argv);
                                                              ^
../../nan/nan.h: In function ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::MakeCallback(v8::Local<v8::Object>, const char*, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’:
../../nan/nan.h:863:62: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> node::MakeCallback(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Object>, const char*, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’ is deprecated (declared at /root/.node-gyp/10.2.1/include/node/node.h:157): Use MakeCallback(..., async_context) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), target, method, argc, argv);
                                                              ^
../../nan/nan.h: In member function ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Nan::Callback::Call_(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Object>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) const’:
../../nan/nan.h:1477:5: warning: ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> node::MakeCallback(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Function>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’ is deprecated (declared at /root/.node-gyp/10.2.1/include/node/node.h:171): Use MakeCallback(..., async_context) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     ));
     ^
make: *** [Release/obj.target/decode/src/common/allocator.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/bilyes/Desktop/keeweb/node_modules/iltorb/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:237:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/bilyes/Desktop/keeweb/node_modules/iltorb
gyp ERR! node -v v10.2.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 

> keytar@4.0.3 install /home/bilyes/Desktop/keeweb/node_modules/keytar
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/home/bilyes/Desktop/keeweb/node_modules/keytar/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/keytar/src/async.o
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:190:0,
                 from ../src/async.cc:3:
../../nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h: In function ‘Nan::Maybe<bool> Nan::ForceSet(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::PropertyAttribute)’:
../../nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:112:15: error: ‘class v8::Object’ has no member named ‘ForceSet’
   return obj->ForceSet(isolate->GetCurrentContext(), key, value, attribs);
               ^
make: *** [Release/obj.target/keytar/src/async.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/bilyes/Desktop/keeweb/node_modules/keytar/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:237:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/bilyes/Desktop/keeweb/node_modules/keytar
gyp ERR! node -v v10.2.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN lifecycle keeweb@1.6.3~postinstall: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s) keeweb@1.6.3 cd desktop && npm install /home/bilyes/Desktop/keeweb
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: grunt-appdmg@0.4.0 (node_modules/grunt-appdmg):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for grunt-appdmg@0.4.0: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: appdmg@0.4.5 (node_modules/appdmg):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for appdmg@0.4.5: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: iltorb@1.0.13 (node_modules/iltorb):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: iltorb@https://registry.npmjs.org/iltorb/-/iltorb-1.0.13.tgz install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: keytar@4.0.3 (node_modules/keytar):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: keytar@4.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

moved 1 package in 40.458s
[root@localhost keeweb]#
```

Those are the versions of `node` and `npm`:

```
[bilyes@localhost keeweb]$ node -v
v10.2.1
[bilyes@localhost keeweb]$ npm -v
5.6.0
```

Comment: Did you tried to update to npm 6.x ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrading to `npm 5.6.1` fixes the building issues, now it compiles fine.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from first couple of lines, you should first try to upgrade your npm to 6.x with `npm i -g npm`

If that won't work, check the node version project was developed on. Try to downgrade your node.

---- edit ----

Look at the module which is failed to build. It depends on couple of native Linux libraries

https://github.com/atom/node-keytar

Try to install all required deps and build again

Comment: Keeweb is developed in node 10.2.1 and npm 5.6.1, I asked the core developer for that, and it is compile successfully on windows with the same versions.

Comment: @HAßdøµ Look at edits I've done ins answer. Possibly you're missing some linux packages